# How to get back to usual font colors with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, themes, visual-studio-2022, color-scheme

Sorry but it's turning me crazy,
I just installed on my new computer Visual Studio 2022 and from here impossible to get back to the usual font colors.

I installed precedent versions, new one, re-installed again, I searched for extensions or themes or whatever. I didn't find a clear answer via google so I ask for your help here.
How I get back to this :

[good colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7gl6.jpg)

Now with Visual Studio 2022 freshly installed without any extensions I have this :

[bad colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R4OT.jpg)

I checked the Fonts and Colors options but do I really need to customize all the colors manually ?
it sounds crazy.

Thanks a lot for the help.
Bests.

Comment: Interesting... I think its something obvious that you/we are missing. How are you opening this file? What is the file extension? I see the first screenshot seems to be some sort of Unity file.  I think Visual Studio has a Unity component that you can install when first installing Visual Studio.  You can check if you installed that via the Visual Studio Installer application and install it if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the file is the same with 3 months difference on two different computer. It’s a .cs file opened via Unity in both case . When I installed VS on my new computer I installed the Unity C# library it asked for, but yes there is something I should miss…

Comment: Also, important update :
It works perfectly fine with Visual Studio Code.
I completely uninstalled Visual Studio Community 2022 and re-installed it again and.... it doesn't work.
So from here I can use Visual Studio Code but I would like to get VS Community working anyway.

Comment: I updated the images with good and bad colors in my original post so you can see more clearly how it's different.

Comment: SOLVED

I was missing 'Regenerate Project Files' in Unity Preferences while choosing VS 2022 as .cs opener.
Apprently CodeLens and IntelliCode couldn't recognize references, structures etc without clicking this option.
Thanks.